How do I get a "fixed effects" row to show up in texreg?
I am having trouble creating two rows that says "display fixed effects" using texreg. This is what I have so far:
library(texreg)
reg <- lm(carb ~ mpg + cyl + disp + hp, mtcars)

texreg(
  reg,
  omit.coef = c("disp"),
  gof = c("Display Fixed Effects"),
  gof.names = c("Display Fixed Effects"))

I want to see additional rows after the coefficients and have "yes" across the board showing that I controlled for state and year level fixed effects. How would I do that in the texreg command without manually adding it into the LaTeX output?

You've been around for a while, so you probably know that including a minimal reproducible example is not only much appreciated, it also makes it much more likely you will receive a useful answer.

Just updated it.

I don't see gof or gof.names as parameters for either texreg() or extract,lm-method
